# What the things I have to do after installation

Tags: 12.04

I am new to ubuntu i installed ubuntu 12.04

so can u give me things to done first after installing ubuntu for the first time

software to speed up the system

terminal tips and basic uses

Answer (score 2):

You can try the Ubuntu Pocket Guide found [here](http://www.ubuntupocketguide.com/index_main.html)

Specifically for Terminal tips , i used the Surrey tutorial and found it extremely helpful. The link is pasted [here](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Teaching/Unix/).

For you to fully understand and get used to it, i advise you to learn through practice because from experience, i noticed there is no substitute to practice. Let me also include similar questions on this same topic that were posted previously and you can use them as a reference
[beginner's manuals](https://askubuntu.com/questions/305163/beginners-manuals)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/51566/what-is-the-best-place-for-learning-how-to-use-ubuntu